# Visible focus using font awsome icon

Tags: css, icons, less, focus

I am trying to set the visible focus when tabbing to a fontawesome icon wrapped in an a href.

```
<a href="#" class="expand_collapse" aria-hidden="true">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
```

If I add a word into the mix. the word gets focus when tabbed to.

```
<a href="#" class="expand_collapse" aria-hidden="true">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
       Hello Bob!
    </a>
```

What is the best way to add a visible focus to the icon area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get focus when tabbing with your exact code. However have you tried adding a tabindex to your a tag?

```
<a href="#" class="expand_collapse" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="1">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Strange I wonder why it's not working for me. I'll double check. Thanks.

Comment: The  (i) element is in the tab index because of the surrounding a href. However when the focus is on the icon area there is no visible indicator like a blue outline. I tried adding :focus to the <a href="#" class="expand_collapse" in the CSS which did not work. The only way I can get a visible focus is by adding text into the a href... :-)

Comment: What browser are you testing in. I get a blue box indicating focus on tab in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome and IE11. I suspect I have a conflict in my CSS somewhere. Thanks for letting me know it works for you.

Comment: Update. Fixed the issue was the positioning of the focusable element. Tabindex was not required. Thanks for all the help